# trigger working on three tables

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

I Have three tables

ms_seller table(seller_id - primary key)

```
seller_id  seller_status vacation_mode
   50             0            1
```

ms_product Table(product_id - primary key)

```
 product_id    seller_id
     9           50
     2           50
```

product table

```
 product_id     date_modified
       2         2017-01-06 16:13:27
       9         2017-01-06 16:13:27
```

My question is

if i am updating seller status or vacation_mode in ms_seller table then according to seller_id 50 , we will pick product_id from ms_product table then according to product_id 2 and 9, I have to update date modified by today date in product table

can we do this ??

thanks for any suggestion

Comment: I hope for your sake you have ISO-8601 dates in `YYYY-MM-DD` format in your database. Using strings like that is nothing but trouble.

Comment: using datetime in date modified

Comment: Yeah, that looks a lot safer. Good to know.

Comment: can we set trigger for this situation

Comment: As a note, this would be a lot easier to run as a batch job that's initiated from your application layer. Sometimes setting this all up as triggers creates this clockwork contraption that's very, very hard to keep operating correctly as it has lots of fiddly moving parts.

Comment: provide any solution if possible